# How to register factory delegate with Microsoft's dependency injection?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I have a service like this:

```cs
public class MyService
{
    public MyService(MyOtherService otherService, string clientId)
    {

    }
}
```

And to the `MyService` class, I've added the following delegate declaration:

```cs
public delegate MyService Factory(string clientId);
```

At present, I'm registering it with the container like so:

```cs
services.AddSingleton<MyService.Factory>(sp =>
{
    var factory = ActivatorUtilities.CreateFactory(typeof(MyService), new Type[] { typeof(string) });
    return new MyService.Factory((clientId) => (MyService)factory(sp, new object[] { clientId }));
});
```

This allows me to inject `MyService.Factory` anywhere, and then call it with a `clientId` value to new up a `MyService`. `MyOtherService` is automatically resolved from the container by the `ActivatorUtilities` factory.

The problem I have with this approach, is that I have a handful of factories such as this, and if I want to add another parameter, etc. I have to update the constructor, the factory, and the factory service registration. The service registration is the worst part since it's in a different place, and a couple of times I've realised that I missed it later than I'd like to.

With Autofac, I used to be able to declare a factory method, and simply register `MyService`. Then `MyService.Factory` was automatically available. Such a system is missing from Microsoft's container.

I'm not necessarily looking for the exact same method, but is there any easier way of registering factory methods without having to do so much manual work to wire them up in the service registration code?

Comment: Are you [sure about using a factory](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2016/abstract-factories-are-a-code-smell/), because it seems that your `MyService` component [requires runtime data to be constructed](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2015/code-smell-injecting-runtime-data-into-components/).

Comment: @Steven You may have a point, I think Autofac has got me into a bad habit with these services. I only have about 4 of them but I should probably look at rearchitecting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution to this was to use expressions to dynamically build the following part of the existing service registration:

```cs
sp =>
{
    var factory = ActivatorUtilities.CreateFactory(typeof(MyService), new Type[] { typeof(string) });
    return new MyService.Factory((clientId) => (MyService)factory(sp, new object[] { clientId }));
}
```

I then tidied it all up and put it in an extension method:

```cs
public static class ServiceExtensionMethods
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddFactoryDelegate<TDelegate>(this IServiceCollection serviceCollecton)
        where TDelegate : Delegate
    {
        Type delegateType = typeof(TDelegate);

        // The invoke method is what will be called when we try to use the factory delegate
        MethodInfo invokeMethod = delegateType.GetMethod("Invoke");

        if (invokeMethod.ReturnType == typeof(void))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The delegate must have a return type.", nameof(TDelegate));
        }

        // Create the factory based on the type we want to create and the parameters of the delegate
        var factory = ActivatorUtilities.CreateFactory(invokeMethod.ReturnType, invokeMethod.GetParameters().Select(p => p.ParameterType).ToArray());
        var factoryExpression = Expression.Constant(factory);
        var factoryMethod = typeof(ObjectFactory).GetMethod("Invoke");

        // The factory delegate takes an IServiceProvider and a parameters array (object[]), 
        // so we'll need to cast our parameters to object
        var parameterExpressions = invokeMethod.GetParameters().Select(p => Expression.Parameter(p.ParameterType)).ToArray();
        var objectParameterExpressions = parameterExpressions.Select(p => Expression.TypeAs(p, typeof(object)));

        // Build our object[] array expression
        var arrayExpression = Expression.NewArrayInit(typeof(object), objectParameterExpressions);

        // Create the factory method call, passing the service provider and parameters array
        var serviceProviderParameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IServiceProvider));
        var factoryCallExpression = Expression.Call(factoryExpression, factoryMethod, serviceProviderParameterExpression, arrayExpression);

        // The factory method returns object, so we need to cast that to the return type
        var resultConversionExpression = Expression.Convert(factoryCallExpression, invokeMethod.ReturnType);

        // Now we can construct our delegate that takes the parameters and returns the instantiated type
        var delegateLambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda<TDelegate>(resultConversionExpression, parameterExpressions);

        // Finally we need to wrap that up in a lambda method
        // that takes an IServiceProvider and returns the delegate as an object:
        var delegateConstructor = Expression.Lambda<Func<IServiceProvider, object>>(delegateLambdaExpression, serviceProviderParameterExpression);

        // Compile the delegate metod factory lambda
        var compiledDelegateFactory = delegateConstructor.Compile();

        // Register the factory against the container
        serviceCollecton.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(TDelegate), compiledDelegateFactory, ServiceLifetime.Singleton));

        return serviceCollecton;
    }
}
```

Now I can register my factory method more simply:

```cs
services.AddFactoryDelegate<MyService.Factory>();
```

With this new way of registering the factory, I no longer have to update the service registration if I need to add a parameter. I simply update the delegate and the constructor, and it all just works.