# Registering as a Delegate then resolving as a Func in Microsoft DI Factory Method pattern

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

Let's assume that we have the following bunch of similar objects

```
public class ViewModel1
{
    public delegate ViewModel1 Factory(List<string> data);

    public ViewModel1(List<string> data, IOtherService service)
    {
    }
}

public class ViewModel2
{
    public delegate ViewModel2 Factory(int data);

    public ViewModel2(int data, IOtherService service)
    {
    }
}
// and so on
```

When creating such an object, we want to resolve `IOtherService` from the container and pass the `data` argument from the business logic (the type of the `data` can be any and different for different objects).

Typically this is done using the factory methods

```
//register
services.AddScoped<ViewModel1.Factory>(sp =>
{
    var factory = ActivatorUtilities.CreateFactory(typeof(ViewModel1), new[] { typeof(List<string>) });
    return data => (ViewModel1)factory.Invoke(sp, new object[] { data });
});

//use
var factory = sp.GetRequiredService<ViewModel1.Factory>();
var vm = factory(new List<string> { "test", "data" });
```

But I need to generalise such an approach to the something like this:

```
public static TModel GetVM<TModel, TData>(this ServiceProvider sp, TData data)
{
    //the problem is here: how to get the type of the factory, corresponding to the `TModel`?
    var factory = sp.GetRequiredService<Func<TData, TModel>>();
    var vm = factory(data);
    return vm;
}

//usage
var vm = sp.GetVM<ViewModel2, int>(data: 42);
```

So, here we want to resolve the generic type `TModel` and we can't just resolve the specific factory delegate type like `ViewModel2.Factory`.
For the Autofac we can use `Func<TData, TModel>` and DI container will find compatible registered delegate and will resolve it successfuly (e.g. `Func<int, ViewModel2> -> ViewModel2.Factory`) - see Delegate Factories. But MS DI does not do such a things out of the box.

So, the question is: how can I resolve `Func<TIn, TRes>` into the compatible registered delegate in MS DI?

Comment: In order to add such behavior to MS.DI, MS.DI requires support for unregistered type resolution (UTR). UTR is the possibility to get a callback from the Container when an unregistered type is requested, in which way the listener can decide what to do (e.g. make a last-minute registration). But MS.DI lacks support for UTR, which means that what you want simply can't be achieved with MS.DI.

Comment: Although, what you can do... is at the end of the registration process go through all registrations and fetch all `Func<T1, T2>` types from all constructors of all registered types (using reflection), and for each found `Func`, make that registration. This is far from perfect, because dependencies of any lazy resolved type (e.g. using `ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<T>` or with ASP.NET Core controllers and views) will be missed.

Comment: That said, complexity typically arises when require applying runtime data during composition of your object graphs. I [consider this](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/p/runtime-data/) a code smell. And you seem to be hit by this complexity. Instead, consider providing the runtime data to your view models *after* the view model is composed. For instance, introduce a `Data` property or an `Initialize(data)` method on your VM instead so the VM can be initialized after composition is complete. In the WPF/MVVM application I'm maintaining we actually take this approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone will needs this functionality, the solution for the initial answer is below. However, I really suggest to take a look at the @Steven's comments and try to reconsider the design.

The following code (based on the https://stackoverflow.com/a/72317274/2011071) will register the given delegate as delegate or as a compatible `Func` depending of the `registerAsFunc` value. It can be also modified to register both versions (delegate and `Func`) in the same time.

```
    public static IServiceCollection AddFactoryDelegate<TDelegate>(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection, bool registerAsFunc = false)
        where TDelegate : Delegate
    {
        var delegateType = typeof(TDelegate);

        // The invoke method is what will be called when we try to use the factory delegate
        // Delegate.Invoke is 100% here as we have constraint so TDelegate is a subclass of Delegate
        var invokeMethod = delegateType.GetMethod("Invoke")!;

        if (invokeMethod.ReturnType == typeof(void))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(@"The delegate must have a return type.", nameof(TDelegate));
        }

        // Create the factory based on the type we want to create and the parameters of the delegate
        var factory = ActivatorUtilities.CreateFactory(invokeMethod.ReturnType, invokeMethod.GetParameters().Select(p => p.ParameterType).ToArray());
        var factoryExpression = Expression.Constant(factory);
        var factoryMethod = typeof(ObjectFactory).GetMethod("Invoke")!;

        // The factory delegate takes an IServiceProvider and a parameters array (object[]), 
        // so we'll need to cast our parameters to object
        var parameterExpressions = invokeMethod.GetParameters().Select(p => Expression.Parameter(p.ParameterType)).ToArray();
        var objectParameterExpressions = parameterExpressions.Select(p => Expression.TypeAs(p, typeof(object)));

        // Build our object[] array expression
        var arrayExpression = Expression.NewArrayInit(typeof(object), objectParameterExpressions);

        // Create the factory method call, passing the service provider and parameters array
        var serviceProviderParameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IServiceProvider));
        var factoryCallExpression = Expression.Call(factoryExpression, factoryMethod, serviceProviderParameterExpression, arrayExpression);

        // The factory method returns object, so we need to cast that to the return type
        var resultConversionExpression = Expression.Convert(factoryCallExpression, invokeMethod.ReturnType);

        // Now we can construct our delegate that takes the parameters and returns the instantiated type
        var delegateLambdaExpression = registerAsFunc
            ? Expression.Lambda(resultConversionExpression, parameterExpressions)
            : Expression.Lambda<TDelegate>(resultConversionExpression, parameterExpressions);

        // Finally we need to wrap that up in a lambda method
        // that takes an IServiceProvider and returns the delegate as an object:
        var delegateConstructor = Expression.Lambda<Func<IServiceProvider, object>>(delegateLambdaExpression, serviceProviderParameterExpression);

        // Compile the delegate method factory lambda
        var compiledDelegateFactory = delegateConstructor.Compile();

        // Register the factory against the container
        serviceCollection.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(GetTypeForRegister(), compiledDelegateFactory, ServiceLifetime.Singleton));

        return serviceCollection;

        Type GetTypeForRegister()
        {
            if (!registerAsFunc)
            {
                return typeof(TDelegate);
            }
            else
            {
                // we need to build the type to register => typeof(Func<arg0, arg1, ..., res>);
                var funcType = Type.GetType($"System.Func`{parameterExpressions.Length + 1}")?.MakeGenericType(parameterExpressions.Select(x => x.Type).Append(invokeMethod.ReturnType).ToArray());
                return funcType ?? throw new Exception("Can't create Func type for the given delegate arguments list and return value");
            }
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
services.AddFactoryDelegate<ViewModel2.Factory>(true);
```